# want to check if condition whether records present in the datatable or not

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

```
   SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select * from app where date='" + dateTimePicker2.Value + "'", connection);
   // MessageBox.Show(cmd1.CommandText);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    da.Fill(dt);
    //dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    connection.Open();
    if (dt.)
    {
        textBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["company"].ToString();
        textBox2.Text = dt.Rows[0]["place"].ToString();
        dateTimePicker1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["date"].ToString();
        textBox3.Text = dt.Rows[0]["time"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {

    }
    connection.Close();
    control_logoff();
    adminlogin();
  }
```

In my application i want to check if data table does not have records it should not throw the error like  there is no row at position 0.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
if(dt.Rows.Count() != 0){}
```

Comment: If this answer helped,can you please mark this as an answer. Thank you

Comment: Hey, you have to click the tick sign which says "click to set this answer as the accepted answer", thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if(dt.Rows.Count > 0) should do it.
```